# A property in Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $(X , \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle)$ be a prehilbert space and let $M \subset X$ be a vector subspace such that $(M , {\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle}_M)$ is a Hilbert space, being
$$
{\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle}_M = {\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle}\big|_{M \times M} : M \times M \to \mathbb{R} \mbox{ (or } \mathbb{C} \mbox{)}\mbox{.}
$$
Let $P_M$ and $P_{M^{\perp}}$ denote the orthogonal projections onto $M$ and $M^\perp$, respectively. Prove that
$$
\|x - u\| = \inf\{\|x - z\| : z \in M^{\perp}\}\mbox{,}
$$
where $u = x - P_M(x)$ and $\|\cdot\|$ is the norm induced by $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ on $X$.

Comment: $\lVert x-z\rVert^2 = \lVert x - u + u-z\rVert^2$

Comment: What can I do with this expression?

Comment: @joseabp91: expand it and use some of your assumptions...

Comment: @user251257: In this case your comment doesn't give me much help.

Comment: Use Daniel's suggestion and think Pythagoras...